# How to hide teamviewer from a toolbar to a system tray?

Tags: notification-area, teamviewer

I am using teamvier for remote access to my computer. So it is running on that computer constantly.

But I do not like a lot of icons in the toolbar. Mostly when I have more than 4 - I started to be irritated :-). I would like to move teamvierer to a system tray. The problem is that I can not find such option in the settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily, assuming you have windows 7:

1) Right click on the taskbar

2) Properties

3) Customize...

4) On Team Viewer icon select Hide icon and notifications

5) Click OK and Done!

Comment: This hides the System Tray icon, and moves it into the little popup section... but how do you stop it from being a Taskbar icon, and move it into the system tray only in the first place?

Comment: @Mir: In the advanced options of TeamViewer check the option for minimize to the system tray (notification area) and then see the answer of Oxize below to workaround the bug that sometimes make appear an extra button for the contacts window.

Comment: I only want to be able to hide notification especially for Windows 10, because it takes up more of the screen on the bottom right corner for me. The Icon can be disabled within the app and icons that are meant to be shown shouldn't be hidden. Otherwise how would someone know what background tasks are running?

Answer (score 1):

With the newer versions, teamviewers computer and contact stays in the toolbar. Just kill the teamviewer service under task manager. Its reload automaticly, but your computer and contacts will be gone in the toolbar. Now just click on Teamviewer in the systemtray and you see the remote program and the computer and contact program together without stuff in the toolbar.

Told this Teamviewer already manny times, but they still didnt resolved this bug. Its there already since Teamviewer 7.

Comment: Although this relates to the taskbar instead of the notification area (aka "system tray") it does workaround the annoying bug of the "ghost" contacts taskbar button.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit old but in Teamviewer 11:

> Options » Advanced » Show Advanced Options » Close To Tray Menu

Answer (score 0):

Using windows 7, just click the icon in the "system tray" (next to the clock), the big icon in the "task-bar" (that's its name) will disappear

Comment: ............what?