# How to prevent TeamViewer from displaying icon in the bottom of screen

Tags: windows-7

Everytime I connect to my laptop through TeamViewer I see a small Window that says TeamViewer and other details as well as an inward arrow. When I click that arrow the Window minimizes but doesn't completely disappear which is obviously very obnoxious just to have to see because of a simple remote connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notification area - How to hide teamviewer from a toolbar to a system tray? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/545497/how-to-hide-teamviewer-from-a-toolbar-to-a-system-tray)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, as the links provided point to preventing the idle program from appearing in the system tray. Alex Torres is asking how to prevent the connection flag from sticking out above the system tray. The smallest it can be is a > character, but it appears he'd like to make it all disappear. I suspect the answer is "not possible."

Comment: @fred_dot_u I see. Are you sure there's not even any 3rd party software that can accomplish this? I mean that is among one of the reasons I posted this thread on Superuser forums rather than Teamviewer forums.